# Overriding Javascript Whole Date Object with another Object

Tags: javascript

I have implemented another object like js built-in `Date` object. How can I replace `Date` with my object? example (this must use `MyDate()` instead of `Date`):

```
var date= new Date();
```

(Because I have many js file that use the object and I need the obj based on another date standard.)

Comment: By using your object anywhere that you would otherwise use `Date`?

Comment: I want to any `Date` in js codes uses my obj instead of `Date`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's bad idea to replace built-in `Date` object. See this article: https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/

If you really want to do this, you do it the same way as with other objects:

```
Date = MyDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
window.Date = 4; // or something else
```

but as @Gothdo said, it is a bad idea and probably will break the entire app if somewhere the Date object is used...

---

Assuming that your code is running in a *browser environment* (different by node and others environemts):

Every global variable is just a window property because the main scope is the window scope... So, when you type `var now = new Date();`, actually, you are typing `var now = new window.Date();`, it is just an abbreviation;

so, if you want to change the `Date`object you can do both:

1. `window.Date = 4`;
2. `Date = 4`;

try by yourself. The only difference is in how the variable is resolved, following the javascript scope-chain.